# I can't change "Type and hit enter to search..." (English) to French in xml

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I can't change the default text "Type and hit enter to search..." to French "Tapez et appuyez sur entrée pour rechercher..."

Here is the code in the xml:

```html
<form class="search-form" id="ajax-search-form" action="/search">
    <input name="q" onfocus='if (this.value == "Type and hit enter to search...") {this.value = "";}' onblur='if 
    (this.value == "") {this.value = "Type and hit enter to search...";}' type="text" value="Type and hit enter to search...">
    
    <button title="Search" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
<div class="src-result" id="search-result"></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your string at the end of `<input>` :

`<input name="q" ...... type="text" value="Write anything here...">`

Here run this snippet:

```html
<form class="search-form" id="ajax-search-form" action="/search">
<input name="q" onfocus='if (this.value == "Type and hit enter to search...") {this.value = "";}' onblur='if 
(this.value == "") {this.value = "Type and hit enter to search...";}' type="text" value="Write anything here...">
<button title="Search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<div class="src-result" id="search-result"></div></form>
```